# Please explain to me prototypes in javascript using the code below

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to use the prototype method of writing functions that can be implemented by strings to capitalise every first letter of every word. I would like to call this function like,

```
var str = "Example of a string";
str.toJadenCase();
```

This is the function I am trying to write:

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    //split the statement into each word
    if (String.prototype.length !== 0)
    {
        var eachWord = String.prototype.split(" ");
        var n = eachWord.length;

        if(n !== 0)
        {
            //loop through the array of words
            for(var i = 0; i < eachWord.length; i++){
                //for each loop, split the word into individual characters
                var charArray = eachWord[i].split("");

                //capitalise the first element of character array
                charArray[0] = charArray[0].toUpperCase();

                //join all elements in character array to string
                eachWord[i] = charArray.join("");
            }

            //join all the words to form the statement
            String.prototype = eachWord.join(" ");
            return String.prototype;
        }
    }
};
```

I had written it this way before:

```
var capitaliseInitial = function(sampleText){
    var textString = sampleText;
    //split the statement into each word
    var eachWord = textString.split(" ");

    //loop through the array of words
    for(var i = 0; i < eachWord.length; i++){
        //for each loop, split the word into individual characters
        var charArray = eachWord[i].split("");

        //capitalise the first element of character array
        charArray[0] = charArray[0].toUpperCase();

        //join all elements in character array to string
        eachWord[i] = charArray.join("");
    }
    //join all the words to form the statement
    textString = eachWord.join(" ");
    return textString;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Jaden? Wanting to use a meme, but would resist from using it :p

Comment: I tried running the code but there is an error. can you spot any?

Comment: `String.prototype = eachWord.join(" ");` is just seriously, seriously wrong.

Comment: @AmitJoki...feel free to use it

Comment: `String.prototype.length !== 0`, `var eachWord = String.prototype.split(" ");` are not right, neither.

Comment: @fuyushimoya, How would you write those statements correctly?

Comment: @NateMartin T.J. Crowder just gave an excellent answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to call this function like,
>
> ```
> var str = "Example of a string";
> str.toJadenCase();
> ```

You can't, strings are immutable. You would have to call it like this:

```
str = str.toJadenCase();
```

In your function, you're using `String.prototype` incorrectly. `String.prototype` is the object containing the various `String`-specific methods. It's assigned as the underlying prototype of all strings.

Where you're using `String.prototype`, you should be using `this`, and instead of trying to assign to it (`this = ...` is invalid), *return* the result.

The simple way to do what you're doing is to:

1. Split the string into an array of words, as you have
2. Loop through that array either building up a new string with the capitalized words via `+=`, or building a new array with the capitalized words and then doing `Array#join` at the end to put it back together.
3. Return the string you built

Something like this:

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function() {
  var result = this;

  //split the statement into each word
  if (this.length !== 0) {
    result = this.split(" ").map(function(word) {
      return word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    }).join(" ");
  }

  return result;
};
snippet.log("this is a test".toJadenCase());
snippet.log("oneword".toJadenCase());
snippet.log("blank: " + ("".toJadenCase()));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note I've done away with the check if the array of words' `length` isn't `0`: It *can't* be `0` if you've pre-checked the length as you have.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: Doh! Thanks, didn't read carefully enough, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

use RegExp and php like naming

> str.ucwords()

```
String.prototype.ucwords = function() {
    return this.replace(/\b\S/g,function(c){
        return c.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did mine.

Split the string into an array of words, as you have
Loop through that array either building up a new string with the capitalized words via +=, or building a new array with the capitalized words and then doing Array#join at the end to put it back together.
Return the string you built

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () { return this.split(" ").map(function(word){ return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1); }).join(" "); }
```

Answer (score 0):

This look like one of the Code Wars Katas - this was my solution -

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    // assign 'this' keyword to a variable and split String into an array
    var result = this.split(" ");

    /* loop through the array changing first character of each item to 
    uppercase & adding it to the remaining letters in each item */

    for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result[i].substring(1);
    }
    //finally return items joined back together in a string
    return result.join(' ');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this would be like:

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function() {
  return this
    .split(" ")
    .map(i => i.replace(i[0], i[0].toUpperCase()))
    .join(" ");
};
```